# Extracting the Minimum x Value Keys from Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose we wish to extract the minimum value from a dictionary like so

```
scores = {
    0:1.3399288498085087,
    1:1.2672683347433629,
    3:1.6999159970296505, 
    4:1.8410942584597279,
    5:1.336658057628646
}

#find minimum value in dictionary
minimum_value = min(scores.values())

#get keys with minimal value using list comprehension
minimum_keys = [key for key in scores if scores[key]==minimum_value]

minimum_keys
```

This returns the key with the lowest value. *However*, what if I wish to extract the minimum 2 keys and put them into a list? What if I wanted the minimum 20? How would I go about doing this for an arbitrary number of minimal values desired?

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Comment: @Rukon although that does allow OP to get an answer, I feel the answer to their specific question about keys is even simpler, as shown below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, the problem is simpler than you think:

```
scores = {
    0:1.3399288498085087,
    1:1.2672683347433629,
    3:1.6999159970296505, 
    4:1.8410942584597279,
    5:1.336658057628646
}

# minimum key
print(min(scores, key=scores.get))

# n minimum keys
print(sorted(scores, key=scores.get)[:3])
```

Output:

```
1
[1, 5, 0]
```

Both `min` and `sorted` allow you to provide a `key` which is some function to be called with a value, to compute an associated value to be used for sorting. By providing `scores.get` as that function, you can sort keys by their matching value, which is what you want.

Comment: very crisp answer. I learnt one new thing today. Thanks @Grismar

Comment: Note that `sorted`, whose time complexity is *O(n log n)*,  is not nearly as efficient as `heapq.nsmallest`, where the time complexity is *O(n log t)*, where *t* is the number of smallest values needed.

Comment: @blhsing that seems to depend on what `n` is according to the [heapq documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) which states `The latter two functions perform best for smaller values of n. For larger values, it is more efficient to use the sorted() function.`

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved as below:

```py
# your dictionary
scores = {
    0:1.3399288498085087,
    1:1.2672683347433629,
    3:1.6999159970296505, 
    4:1.8410942584597279,
    5:1.336658057628646
}

# a list to store keys
min_keys = []

# how many minimum keys you need
count = 2

# iterate over dict items, sorted based on values 
for key,val in sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])[:count]:
    min_keys.append(key)
    
print(min_keys)
# prints [1,5]
```

Comment: This is just a rewrite of the answer linked to by user @rukon. If you believe this is the answer to this question, you should not post it here, since that would make this question a duplicate.